# Where was Admiral Ackbar when the Battle of Scarif happened?

Tags: star-wars, rogue-one

I was thinking that when watching *Rogue One* I did not hear or see any mention of Admiral Ackbar during the film. On further investigation I found no mention of Scarif on [his Wookieepedia page](https://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Gial_Ackbar) or of him on the [Battle of Scarif](https://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Battle_of_Scarif) page. **So where was Admiral Ackbar while the Battle of Scarif was raging?**

Comment: He probably thought it was a trap and stayed home.

Comment: His Wookiepedia page does have this note `Ackbar was in the original script for the 2016 film Rogue One: A Star Wars Story but the part was ultimately changed to Admiral Raddus after Ackbar appeared in the 2015 film Star Wars: Episode VII The Force Awakens`

Comment: @Machavity, any note on why he needed to be changed when he appeared in TFA? His contract states he can only appear in a single Star Wars battle per decade?

Comment: As the linked Wookieepedia page says he was spaced along with Leia and died.

Comment: @IG_42 Ackbar died in *The Last Jedi* in 34 ABY, after *The Force Awakens*. *Rogue One* takes place a LONG time before *TFA*, in 15-0 BBY. He was certainly alive in the *RO* timeframe (he was born sometime before 50 BBY) and could have made an appearance if they wanted him to.

Comment: Oh got my planets mixed up

Comment: @Quasi_Stomach his contract can't withstand roles of that magnitude!

Comment: He was getting lunch at the Admiral Snackbar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We don't know where he physically was, but he was apparently unable to adequately provide support in the battle.

Accordining to *[Star Wars: The Rebel Files](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Rebel_Files)*, his forces were "Shorthanded, behind schedule, underequipped, and hardly in a position to supplant Raddus and bolster the rebel fleet."